# How itis possible we have a coherent matrix with the code below?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, matrix

The author says: The array stores its content in a single array of width × height elements. The elements are stored row by row, so, for example, the third element in the fifth row is (using zero-based indexing) stored at position 4 × width + 2.
the problem is how it is possible to have a coherent array if say the width is 5 when the index will never reach no 2 because of the equation in the square brackets;

```
   let content = [];
   function element(x,y){return undefined;}

for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    content[y * width + x] = element(x, y);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry can you explain better what do you mean by coherent array? And I don't think I understood correctly why do you mean by the "the index will never reach no 2"?

Comment: What use is this?: `function element(x,y){return undefined;}` Plus `height` and `width` are never defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I am not sure I understood correctly your question but I try to explain to you the code you have wrote.

As you have wroten, the code represents 2D matrix as one dimensional array. So if we want to create a 3 x 2 matrix, which would look like this (logicaly)

```
undefinded0, undefinded1
undefinded2, undefinded3
undefinded4, undefinded5
```

(i put a number to make think easier)
if we use your function the representation would look like this

```
[undefined0, undefined1, undefined2, undefined3, undefined4, undefined5]
```

> the problem is how it is possible to have a coherent array if say the width is 5 when the index will never reach no 2 because of the equation in the square brackets

Yep thats true, the array has only one dimension, which means there will be only one element that stays at index 2.
I think you may have confuse the one line representation with some sort bidimensional representation. Here let me do an example. If you have the matrix like this

```
[
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
]
```

Each row (even the fifth row) will have an element with index 2, this is the representation above has two dimensions.

Comment: i think i confused the wole thing and you solved it for me,thank you.